# Sum of values at common indexes in all subsets?

Tags: c++, recursion

In a recent problem where i have to sum all values at common indexes in all possible subsets of size **k** in array of size **n**.

For eg: If

```
array ={1,2,3}
```

Its subsets (k=2) will be (x [i] , x [j]) where i < j

```
1 2
1 3
2 3
Sum:4,8
```

Firstly I have used recursion (same that of generating all subsets)

```
int sum_index[k]={0};
void sub_set(int array[],int n,int k,int temp[],int q=0,int r=0)
{
    if(q==k)
    {
       for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
          sum_index[i]+=temp[i];
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=r;i<n;i++)
        {
            temp[q]=array[i];
            sub_set(value,n,k,temp,q+1,i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is its taking too much time then expected .

Then i modified it to...

```
void sub_set(int array[],int n,int k,int temp[],int q=0,int r=0)
{
    if(q==k)
    {
       return;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=r;i<n;i++)
        {
            temp[q]=array[i];
            sum_index[q]+=temp[q];  //or sum_index[q]+=s[i];
            sub_set(value,n,k,temp,q+1,i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Still taking too much time!!

Is there any other approach to this problem??  Or any other modification i needed that i am unaware of??

Comment: Is `value` declared outside of the function?

Comment: _"Time Limit exceeded"_ From which actual test case does this come? Show the relevant code please.

Comment: I´m still thinking, but there is maybe a faster way which has nothing to do with recursion at all. Your solution isn´t bad, but if you want speed, it´s the wrong approach.

Comment: This is a known NP-complete problem. And as far as I know, there is no way to solve it without recursion.

Comment: @SergeyA Strictly speaking, "without recursion" is *always* possible (but maybe not faster than recursion)

Comment: @SergeyA - You can turn recursive routines into iterative ones.  For example, the OP could have used `next_permutation` and some additional logic to get the subsets instead of recursion.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, it is possible technically (as deviantfan pointed out, you can always implement recursion yourself by doing the stack and pushing and popping your state to/from stack on every iteration) it is not going to be any faster than natural recursion. And I call this a recursive solution because it is logically. Non-recursive solution to this problem is unknown to me, and I doubt it exists :) If you can do this, please post the code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ constraints 1<=n,k<=1000

Comment: @deviantfan faster one is possible, as i just have to take sums not actual subsets, so if there was a way i could know value at index [i] is repeated how many times i could just come up with a formula but i dont know how??

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Possible as i said above

Comment: @wrangler I have a solution (O(n^2) instead of O(n!)), but I can´t write an answer just now. Hopefully in 15-20 min. (Actually, it´s not complicated at all) (and no, this isn´t NP)

Comment: @deviantfan can you post the code??

Comment: @wrangler Sorry for the delay, made the post just now. As promised, O(n^2).

Comment: @SergeyA What´s the name of the NP problem you were referring too? Apparently something is different, because I solved in polynomial time.

Comment: @wrangler Just an addition, the description actually is more complicted than expected, but there is working code too...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating through the possible sub-sets, think of it a combinatorics problem.

To use your example of k=2 and {1,2,3}, let's just look at the first value of the result.  It has two 1's and one 2.  The two 1's correspond to the number one element sets that can be made from {2, 3} and the one 2 corresponds to the number of one element sets that can be made from {3}.  A similar arrangement exists for the one 2 and two 3's in the second element of the result and looking at the subsets of the elements that appear before the element being considered.

Things get a bit more complicated when k>2 because then you will have to look for the number of combinations of elements before and after the element being considered, but the basic premise still works.  Multiply the number of possible subsets before times the number of subsets afterwards and that will tell you how many times each element contributes to the result.

Comment: This approach i mentioned in above comments but first problem is how?? and second k and n are unknown so complexity will sure increase as k and n increases.....easier it sounds but harder to implement.

Comment: @wrangler Since this sounds like a programming contest problem, particularly the "Problem: Time Limit Exceeded," I don't want to spell it out completely for you.

Comment: This should help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations

Comment: It was a contest problem but now its over thats why i have asked after its been closed !!

Answer (score 1):

A solution in O(n^2) instead of O(n!):
First a tiny (:)) bit of explanation, then some code:

I´m going to assume here that your array is sorted (if not, use `std::sort` first). Additionally, I´m going to work with the array values 1,2,3,4... here, if you array consists arbitrary values (like `2 8 17`), you´ll have to think of it as the indices (ie. 1=>2, 2=>8 etc.)

Definition: `(x choose y)` means the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), how it is calculated is in the link too. If you have an array size a and some k for the subset size, `(a choose k)` is the number of permutations, eg. 3 for your example: (1,2), (1,3) and (2,3).

You want the sum for each column if you write the permutations under each other, this would be easy if you knew for each column how many times each array element occurs, ie. how many 1´s, 2´s and 3´s for the first, and how many for second column (with k=2).

Here a bigger example to explain: (1,2,3,4,5) and all possible k´s (each in one block):

```
1
2
3
4
5

12
13
14
15
23
24
25
34
35
45

123
124
125
134
135
145
234
235
245
345

... (didn´t write k=4)

12345
```

Let´s introduce column indices, `0<=c<k`, ie. c=0 means the first column, c=1 the second and so on; and the array size `s=5`.

So, looking eg. at the `k=3`-block, you´ll notice that the lines beginning with 1 (column c=0) have all permutations of the values (2,3,4,5) for `k=2`, more generally a value x in column c has all permutations for values `x+1` to `s` after it. The values from from `x+1` to `s` are `s-x` different values, and after column c there are `k-c-1` more columns. So, for a value x, you can calculate `((s-x) choose (k-c-1))`.
Additionally, the first column has only the values 1,2,3, the last *two* numbers are not here because after this column there are *two* more columns.

If you do this for the first column, it works well. Eg. with value 1 in the first column of k=3 above:
`count(x) = ((s-x) choose (k-c-1)) = (4 choose 2) = 6`
and indeed there are six 1 there. Calculate this count for every array value, multiply `x*count(x)`, and sum it up for every x, that´s the result for the first column.

The other columns are a tiny bit harder, because there can be multiple "permutation blocks" of the same number. To start with, the step above needs a small adjustment: You need a muliplier array somewhere, one multiplier for each array value, and in the beginning each multiplier is 1. In the calculation `x*count(x)` above, take `x*count(x)*muliplier(x)` instead.

In the `k=3`-example, 1 in the first column can be followed by 2,3,4, 2 can be followed by 3,4, and 3 by 4. So the 3-based permutations of the second column need to be counted twice, and the 4-based even three times; more generally so many times like there are smaller values in the previos colums. Multiply that to the current multiplier.

...
Some code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

// factorial (x!)
unsigned long long fact(unsigned char x)
{
    unsigned long long res = 1;
    while(x)
    {
        res *= x;
        x--;
    }
    return res;
}

//binomial coefficient (n choose k)
unsigned long long binom(unsigned char n, unsigned char k)
{
    if(!n || !k) return 1;
    return (fact(n) / fact(k)) / fact(n-k);
}

//just for convenience
template<class T> void printvector(std::vector<T> data)
{
    for(auto l : data) cout << l << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

std::vector<unsigned long long> calculate(std::vector<int> data, int k)
{
    std::vector<unsigned long long> res(k, 0); //result data
    std::vector<unsigned long long> multiplier(data.size(), 1);
    if(k < 1 || k > 255 || data.size() < 1) return res; //invalid stuff
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end()); //as described

    for(int column = 0; column < k; column++) //each column separately
    {
        //count what to multiply to the multiplier array later
        std::vector<unsigned long long> newmultiplier(data.size(), 0);

        //for each array element in this column
        for(int x = column; x <= (data.size() + column - k); x++)
        {
            //core calculation
            res[column] += data[x] * multiplier[x] * binom(data.size() - x - 1, k - column - 1);
            //counting the new multiplier factor
            for(int helper = x + 1; helper < data.size(); helper++)
                newmultiplier[helper]++;
        }
        //calculating new multiplier
        for(int x = 0; x < data.size(); x++)
        {
            if(newmultiplier[x])
                multiplier[x] *= newmultiplier[x];
        }
    }

    return res;
}

int main() {
    printvector(calculate({1,2,3}, 2)); //output 4 8
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don´t worry, this was fun and exactly what I needed after writing boooring code the whole day.

Comment: A side note: For arrays or k´s large enough that the results (and/or intermediate values) won´t fit into `unsigned long long`, it won´t work as it is now. If necessary, one could use some Bigint class/lib with the same algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

`std::next_permutation` may help:

```
std::vector<int> sub_set(const std::vector<int>& a, int k)
{
    std::vector<int> res(k, 0);
    std::vector<bool> p(a.size() - k, false);
    p.resize(a.size(), true);

    do
    {
        int index = 0;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i != p.size(); ++i) {
            if (p[i]) {
                res[index++] += a[i];
            }
        }
    } while (std::next_permutation(p.begin(), p.end()));
    return res;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/ZkAIEv)